# Non-Turing Recognisable Languages

Tags: computability, turing-machines, decidability

After a lot of searching I came to the conclusion that yes, there are languages that are ***not* even Turing Recognisable**, but I can't get good examples which are simple to understand.

Also, I wanna know that what are the **properties** of a language which is non-Turing Recognisable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll answer your questions in order.
First, what is a "simple" example of a language which is not Turing recognizable:

If $\mathcal{H}$ is the halting problem, then I claim $\mathcal{H}^c$ (that is, the *complement* of $\mathcal{H}$) is not recognizable. Why might this be true?

---

Lemma: For any language $\mathcal{L}$, if $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}^c$ are both recognizable, then actually $\mathcal{L}$ is *decidable*.

Let $w$ be a word, and fix Turing machines $M$ and $M^c$ for $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}^c$ respectively. If $w \in \mathcal{L}$, then $M(w)$ will halt and accept. If instead $w \not \in \mathcal{L}$, then $M^c(w)$ will halt and accept. Thus, if we run $M$ and $M^c$ in parallel, we know that one of them will halt! Depending on which one it is, we will know if $w \in \mathcal{L}$ or not.

---

Now, we *know* that $\mathcal{H}$ is

- Recognizable
- *Not* decidable

Then if $\mathcal{H}^c$ *were* recognizable, $\mathcal{H}$ would be decidable (by the above lemma) and we contradict.

Concretely, $\mathcal{H}^c = \{ \langle M, x \rangle ~|~ M \text{ codes a Turing machine which _doesn't_ halt on input } x \}$ is not recognizable.

---

As for what some *properties* of these languages would be, it becomes harder and harder to say as we move up the complexity hierarchy. Though it might be worth reading about [The Arithmetical Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy). We can classify families of languages based on how complicated they are, and there are many results in this area, though they tend to be somewhat cumbersome and abstract.

---

I hope this helps ^_^